# How to create a table in HTML from data in a database using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to display a table using info from a database. I can see all the data being displayed with my console.log, but I'm not sure how to then put that into a table.

here is my updated version. it's now showing the at least an operator but only one operator and not all of them. How can I get it to show all operators??

```
function displayDataTable(index){

allocationDataAjax = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./qry/getAllocationData.php",
    async: true,
    data: {ModelId: control.settings.modelId},
    success: function(result){
        allocationData = JSON.parse(result);

        for (i=0;i<allocationData.length;i++){
            //console.log(allocationData["SystemName"][i], allocationData["Operator"][i]);
            var operator = allocationData["SystemName"][i];
            console.log(operator);
        }

        $("#dataTableDiv").html(allocationData);
        $("#pageOverlay").empty();
            html = "<div id='dataTableDiv'><h4>Data Table</h4><table id='dataTable' class='table table-bordered table-striped dataTable' role='grid'><thead><tr role='row'><th>header 1</th><th>header 2</th><th>header 3</th><th>header 4</th><th>header 5</th><th>header 6</th></thead></tr><tbody><tr><td>" + operator + "</td></tr></tbody></table><input type='button' value='Close' onclick='closeOverlay()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' id='exportDataTable' value='Export Table'></div>";
        $("#pageOverlay").html(html);
        }
   });
```

Comment: Try $("#dataTableDiv").html(result)

Comment: @DinoMyte that shows all of the data but not in a table

Comment: is 'result' object an html string ?

Comment: @DinoMyte no it's not

Comment: you can only append string html to an html element. You would need to convert the object or json string to html string first

Comment: @DinoMyte so I fixed it and it is a string.. see my updated version. I'm getting an operator now but not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer just in case anyone else runs into this issue in the future

```
function displayDataTable(index){

   allocationDataAjax = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./qry/getAllocationData.php",
      async: true,
      data: {ModelId: control.settings.modelId},
      success: function(result){
        allocationData = JSON.parse(result);

        $("#pageOverlay").empty();

        html = "<div id='dataTableDiv'><h4>Data Table</h4><table id='dataTable' class='table table-bordered table-striped dataTable' role='grid'><thead><tr role='row'><th>System Name</th><th>Gatherer</th><th>Operator</th><th>County</th><th>Sample Date</th><th>Daily Avg</th></thead></tr><tbody>";

        for (i=0;i<allocationData.length;i++){
            //console.log(allocationData);
            //console.log(allocationData["SystemName"][i], allocationData["Operator"][i]);

            html += "<tr><td>" + allocationData['SystemName'][i] + "</td><td>" + allocationData['Gatherer'][i] + "</td><td>" + allocationData['Operator'][i] + "</td><td>" + allocationData['County'][i] + "</td><td>" + allocationData['SampleDate'][i] + "</td><td>" + allocationData['DailyAvg'][i] + "</td></tr>";

        }

        html += "</tbody></table><input type='button' value='Close' onclick='closeOverlay()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' id='exportDataTable' value='Export Table'></div>";

        $("#pageOverlay").html(html);
}
```